# Reduce random integer by -1 depending on user input

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing this program where the user can interact with a "pet". 
The pet is supposed to have a random thirst, hunger and irritability level.
And the user should be able to reduce the level by feeding (lowers the hunger score), singing (lowers the irritability score) and given water to (lowers thirst level).

I've made some changes to it now and was wondering how I could store the emotional states to an array instead

I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate any advice.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class petInteraction
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    petEmotion();
    System.exit(0);
} //ENDS main

    public static String petInteraction() //Use this further on in petEmotion()
    {
        String petName;
        petName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your pet called?");
        System.out.println("Oh cool, " + petName + " is a very unique name!");
        Random emotion = new Random();
        int hungerLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;

        if (hungerLVL == 1 || hungerLVL == 2 || hungerLVL == 3)
        {
            System.out.println(petName + " is feeling Calm.");
        }
        else if (hungerLVL == 4 || hungerLVL == 5 || hungerLVL == 6 )
        {
            System.out.println(petName + " is feeling tetchy!");
        }
        else if (hungerLVL == 7 || hungerLVL == 8 || hungerLVL == 9 || hungerLVL == 10 )
        {
            System.out.println(petName + " is DANGEROUS RIGHT NOW!!!.");
        }
        return petName;
    } //ENDS petInteraction

                public static void petEmotion() //This method changes the emotional states of the pet.
                {
                    String petname;
                    petname = petInteraction();

                        for (int round =1; round <=4; round++) //Generate random values for the Pet's emotional levels.         

                        {
                        Random emotion = new Random();
                        int irritabilityLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
                        int thirstLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
                        int hungerLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;

                        System.out.println(petname + "'s irrtability level is " + irritabilityLVL);
                        System.out.println(petname + "'s thirst level is " + thirstLVL);
                        System.out.println(petname + "'s hunger level is " + hungerLVL);    

                        String askToReduceIrritable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to sing for " + petname + " in order to lower the pets irritability level?");

                            if (askToReduceIrritable.equals("Yes") || askToReduceIrritable.equals ("yes"))
                            {
                                irritabilityLVL = irritabilityLVL - 1;
                                System.out.println(petname + "'s irrtability level is now " + irritabilityLVL);                         
                            }   

                            String askToReduceThirst = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + petname + " some water in order to reduce the thirst level?");

                            if (askToReduceThirst.equals("Yes") || askToReduceThirst.equals ("yes"))
                            {
                                thirstLVL = thirstLVL - 1;
                                System.out.println(petname + "'s thirst level is now " + thirstLVL);                            
                            }   

                            String askToReduceHunger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + petname + " some food in order to reduce the hunger level?");

                            if (askToReduceHunger.equals("Yes") || askToReduceHunger.equals ("yes"))
                            {
                                hungerLVL = hungerLVL - 1;
                                System.out.println(petname + "'s hunger level is now " + hungerLVL);                            
                            }           
                            System.out.println("");
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A new round has begun!");
                        }
                }//ENDS petEmotion


} //ENDS Class alientpetprogram
```

Comment: Are you sure it loops? You don't have any infinite loop at first sight.

Comment: The first step is to use a debugger and set a breakpoint on the `if` statement. Look at the value of `askToReduceIrritable`, and then see whether you enter the conditional block.

Comment: You should think about storing the state of your pet in a scope that extends outside of those methods : http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html - your current approach is unlikely to work out.

Comment: You should use `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` for checking for case-insensitive `String`s. Your check to see if `askToReduceIrritable` will fail if `askToReduceIrritable = "yEs"` or `askToReduceIrritable = "YEs"`, or any other alternative.

Comment: I just ran your code... it asked me for the pets name, then asked me 4 times if I wanted to lower its irritability, then exited. Are you seeing/expecting something different?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I just confused myself. Right now I'm trying to fix the print format:

asda's irrtability level is 10
asda's thirst level is 1
asda's hunger level is 7
asda's irrtability level is now 9
asda's irrtability level is 7

When the input dialog pops up and I type yes, it shows that the level has become -1, but it then prints out another level immediately.

Comment: I don't know why it would become `-1`... One problem I think you are facing is in each iteration of the for loop you are resetting the pet levels so they are going to keep changing randomly despite the users actions.